# Python 'midi' has no attribute 'Pattern'

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

Recently I've been trying out machine learning with tensorflow. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE7qWXX05T0), has me stuck because I keep getting the error: `AttributeError: module 'midi' has no attribute 'Pattern'` Does anyone know how to fix this error? I've tried installing py-midi (pip), python-midi (github), and the midi module (pip). However, the midi module never installed properly (*"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement midi"*). I'm using python 3.5

My code:
`import midi
 pattern = midi.Pattern()
 track = midi.Track()
 pattern.append(track)`

-Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Verifiable, and Complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I don't think many people are going to watch that whole video to try to recreate your error.

Comment: Just edited, added the basic parts of my code.

Comment: Have you installed midi using PIP? And which module? pip install midi?

Comment: I've tried: py-midi, [python-midi](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi/tree/feature/python3), and [the midi module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/midi), however, I couldn't get the midi module installed.

Comment: When asking about an error in Python code, you need to copy the full traceback, including the lines preceding the `AttributeError`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this error by installing the module directly from git: `pip install git+https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi@feature/python3` Found this command on  [this](https://github.com/llSourcell/Music_Generator_Demo/issues/12#issuecomment-301073063) github page.